# Closed form solution to optimization problem with mixed quadratic and linear constraints

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

Does the following optimization problem have a closed form solution?

$$\max_{\mathbf{u}\in\mathbb{C}^{N}} |\mathbf{u}^H \mathbf{h}|^2 $$
$$\text{s.t.} \ \ \mathbf{u}^H \mathbf{g}_i = 0, \ i\in\{1,\ldots, K\} $$
$$ ||\mathbf{u}||\leq 1$$
where $\mathbf{h}$ and $\mathbf{g}_i$ are complex vectors, $\mathbf{g}_i$ are linearly independent and $K<<N$.

Edit: I have done the following. Is it correct?

Let $\mathbf{G}:=[\mathbf{g}_1 \ \mathbf{g}_2 \ldots \mathbf{g}_K]\in \mathbb{C}^{N\times K}$. We want $\mathbf{G}^H \mathbf{u}=0$. Let's apply SVD to $\mathbf{G}^H$. We have
$$\mathbf{G}^H=\mathbf{U}\Sigma\mathbf{V}^H =\mathbf{U}\Sigma[\mathbf{V}_1 \ \mathbf{V}_0]^H$$
where $\mathbf{U}\in\mathbb{C}^{K\times K}$ and $\mathbf{V}\in\mathbb{C}^{N\times N}$ are unitary matrices, $\Sigma\in\mathbb{C}^{K\times N}$ is a diagonal matrix of singular values, $\mathbf{V}_1\in\mathbb{C}^{K\times K}$ and $\mathbf{V}_0\in\mathbb{C}^{K\times (N-K)}$ are the submatrices of the right-singular vectors corresponding to non-zero and zero singular values. Then, because the columns of $\mathbf{V}_0$ are of norm one, the optimal value of $\mathbf{u}$ is the column of $\mathbf{V}_0$ that maximizes $|\mathbf{u}^H\mathbf{h}|^2$.

The above solution doesn't give a closed-form solution though.

Comment: Some hints: 1. The objective scales quadratically with $\|u\|$, so you can ignore all points $\|u\|<1$. 2. The linear constraint can be removed by writing $u = \left(I - \frac{gg^H}{\|g\|^2}\right)v$ for some $v\in\mathbb{C}^N$.

Comment: Thank you. I just edited my question. There are actually a set of linear constraints. Although I think I can condense them into one constraint by concatenating the $\mathbf{g}_i$'s into a matrix.

Comment: You can by constructing an orthogonal basis of the subspace spanning the $g_i$'s then projecting away from that. Then you can just take the derivative and set it equal to zero.

Comment: Let $v_k$ be an orthonormal basis for the orthogonal complement of the span of the $g_k$ and let $V$ be the matrix whose columns are $v_k$. Then the $\max$ value is given by $\|V^H h\|^2$.

Comment: @copper.hat What is the optimal value of $\mathbf{u}$ based on your solution?

Comment: $u= {V V^* h \over \|V^* h\| }$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's denote $\mathbf{u} = (\mathbf{u}_1 \ \mathbf{u}_0 )'$ where $\mathbf{u}_1 \in \mathbb{C}^{K\times1}$ and $\mathbf{u}_0 \in \mathbb{C}^{(N-K)\times1}$, then
$$\mathbf{0}_{K}=\mathbf{G}^H\mathbf{u}=\mathbf{U}\Sigma \cdot(\mathbf{V}_1 \ \mathbf{V}_0)^H\cdot (\mathbf{u}_1 \ \mathbf{u}_0 )= \mathbf{U}\Sigma \cdot(\mathbf{V}_1^H\mathbf{u}_1+\mathbf{V}_0^H \mathbf{u}_0 )$$
$$ \iff  \underbrace{\left(\mathbf{U}\Sigma \mathbf{V}_1^H \right)}_{\in\mathbb{C}^{K\times K}}\mathbf{u}_1 = -\left(\mathbf{U}\Sigma \mathbf{V}_0^H \right)\mathbf{u}_0$$
$$\iff \mathbf{u}_1 = \underbrace{\left(\mathbf{U}\Sigma \mathbf{V}_1^H \right)^{-1}\left(\mathbf{U}\Sigma \mathbf{V}_0^H \right)}_{:=\mathbf{Z}^H\in\mathbb{C}^{K\times (N-K)}}\mathbf{u}_0 \tag{1}$$
$(1)$ holds if and only if $\text{rank}(\mathbf{G})=K$ (in this case, the matrix $\mathbf{U}\Sigma \mathbf{V}_1^H$ is inversible.

From the constraint $|\mathbf{u}|^2  \le 1$, we have
$$\begin{align}
|(\mathbf{Z}^H\mathbf{u}_0 \ \ \ \mathbf{u}_0)|^2 \le 1 \\
&\iff |\mathbf{Z}^H\mathbf{u}_0 |^2 +|\mathbf{u}_0 |^2 \le 1\\
&\iff \mathbf{u}_0^H\underbrace{\mathbf{Z}\mathbf{Z}^H}_{\in \mathbb{C}^{(N-K)\times (N-K)}}\mathbf{u}_0 +\mathbf{u}_0^H\mathbf{u}_0 \le 1\\
&\iff \mathbf{u}_0^H\left( \mathbf{Z}\mathbf{Z}^H + \mathbb{I}_{N-K}\right)\mathbf{u}_0  \le 1\tag{2}
\end{align}$$
where $\mathbb{I}_{N-K}$ is the identiy matrix.

We assume that the matrix $\mathbf{Z}\mathbf{Z}^H + \mathbb{I}_{N-K}$ is definite positive (I think this statement is true. I let you prove it or verify it by a numerical method), then we can define an inversible matrix $\Gamma \in \mathbb{C}^{(N-K)\times (N-K)}$ such that
$$\Gamma^H \Gamma =\mathbf{Z}\mathbf{Z}^H + \mathbb{I}_{N-K}$$
Then
$$(2) \iff \mathbf{u}_0^H \Gamma^H \Gamma  \mathbf{u}_0 \le 1 \iff |\Gamma  \mathbf{u}_0 |^2 \le 1\tag{3}$$
Denote $\mathbf{h} = (\mathbf{h}_1 \ \mathbf{h}_0 )'$ where $\mathbf{h}_1 \in \mathbb{C}^{K\times1}$ and $\mathbf{h}_0 \in \mathbb{C}^{(N-K)\times1}$, we have:
$$
\begin{align}
L&:= |\mathbf{h}^H\mathbf{u} |^2\\
&= |(\mathbf{h}_1\ \mathbf{h}_0) ^H(\mathbf{u}_1\ \mathbf{u}_0) |^2\\
&= |\mathbf{h}_1^H\mathbf{u}_1 + \mathbf{h}_0^H\mathbf{u}_0 |^2\\
&= |(\mathbf{h}_1^H \mathbf{Z}^H +\mathbf{h}_0^H) \mathbf{u}_0 |^2\\
&= |(\mathbf{Z}\mathbf{h}_1 +\mathbf{h}_0)^H \mathbf{u}_0 |^2 \\
&= |(\mathbf{Z}\mathbf{h}_1 +\mathbf{h}_0)^H \Gamma^{-1}\cdot \Gamma \mathbf{u}_0 |^2 \tag{4}
\end{align}$$

Applying the [Cauchy–Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Cn_-_n-dimensional_Complex_space) to $(4)$ and using $(3)$, we have:
$$L \le |(\mathbf{Z}\mathbf{h}_1 +\mathbf{h}_0)^H \Gamma^{-1}  |^2\cdot|\Gamma \mathbf{u}_0 |^2 \le \color{red}{ |(\mathbf{Z}\mathbf{h}_1 +\mathbf{h}_0)^H \Gamma^{-1}  |^2}$$

The equality occurs if and only if:

- $\mathbf{u}_1 = \mathbf{Z}^H\mathbf{u}_0$
- The vector $\Gamma \mathbf{u}_0$ has the same direction as the vector $(\mathbf{Z}\mathbf{h}_1 +\mathbf{h}_0)^H \Gamma^{-1}$
- $|\Gamma \mathbf{u}_0| = 1$

from the two last conditions, you deduce $\mathbf{u}_0$ and after that find $\mathbf{u}_1$ with the first condition.